# How to modify a timestamp column?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have received a SQL dump file for an existing database
There is a table with date_from and date_to columns they are both type timestamp
but date_to column has a default value of "0000-00-00 00:00:00".
and when trying to add softdeletes to this table like following :

```
Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->softDeletes();
});
```

i got the following error : Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column `.`.`date_to`

so i tried to make the date_to column nullable as follows :

```
Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('date_to')->nullable()->change();
        $table->softDeletes();
});
```

but according to laravel docs, timestamp column is not modifiable : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#modifying-columns

what would you do in this situation?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read about **DATETIME** and **TIMESTAMP**:

Both the data types store data in “YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS” format and include date as well as time. In spite of these similarities they are having the following differences −

**Range** − Datetime data type supports a date along with time in the range between 1000-01-01 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59. But timestamp data type supports a date along with time in the range between ‘1970-01-01 00:00:01’ to ‘2038-01-19 08:44:07’.

**Size** − Datetime requires 5 bytes along with 3 additional bytes for fractional seconds’ data storing. On the other hand, timestamp datatype requires 4 bytes along with 3 additional bytes for fractional seconds’ data storing. But before MySQL 5.6.4, DateTime requires 8 bytes along with 3 additional bytes for fractional seconds’ data storing.

**Conversion from one timezone to other** − Actually in MySQL5+, timestamp value converts from current time to UTC and vice-versa while datetime does not do any conversion.

**Indexing** − Indexing can be done on timestamp data but datetime data cannot be indexed.

**Caching** of query − queries having timestamp datatype can be cached but queries having datetime datatype cannot be cached.

So you can not store datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column `date_to`

The `change()` method allows you to modify `type and attributes` of existing columns not modify `value`

Try drop the timestamp column, and re-add it as nullable timestamp column:

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('date_to');
        });

        Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamp('date_to')->nullable();
        });
    }

/**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('date_to');
        });

        Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamp('date_to');
        });
    }
```

Read more here: [What is the difference between MySQL DATETIME and TIMESTAMP data type?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-MySQL-DATETIME-and-TIMESTAMP-data-type#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20MySQL%20DATETIME%20and%20TIMESTAMP%20data%20type%3F,-MySQLMySQLi%20Database&text=Range%20%E2%88%92%20Datetime%20data%20type%20supports,08%3A44%3A07%27.)

Comment: Your solution will attempt to insert a "date_to" column which already exists in the table.
I'm trying to make it nullable instead of having a default value of "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: oh, my bad, i think you create it, not change, sorry! i will edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to what you attempted is to add manually the deleted_at column, like this:

```
Schema::table('gamesessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
});
```

and in your **gamesession model**:

```
class Gamesession extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

     /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, the problem is not how I insert the "deleted_at" column but the migration is checking the structure of the table "gamesessions" and it finds a column "date_to" with an invalid default datetime value, that's what is blocking the migration